# Want to Reduce "shininess" of Model

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am creating a poker chip model for Tabletop Simulator.  When I import it it's quite shiny, that is, it reflects light, and I don't want that.
My research indicates that I have to modify the node and do something with specularity.  However, when I change to node mode Blender tells me that no node is available.

Comment: Are you using blender internal or cycles?

Comment: Are you sure your mesh has a material assigned to it.

Comment: "Are you using blender internal or cycles?" -Sorry, i don't know what that means.

Comment: "Are you sure your mesh has a material assigned to it?" -I am not sure how to tell, or how to assign one if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In blender internal set the Specular Intensity value to a smaller (or Zero) value.

[image]